# If-Else rules to hard code the parsing of an address

Tags: python, regex, if-statement

I want to start with a hard-coded, rule based structure in Python, preferably
using IF-ELSE to solve the following:

For example, I have this properly formatted

```
UK postal address:
Flat 8, The Apartment, King Philip Street, SE1 3WX
```

The different variations that can be derived from the above Actual address are:

These ones focuses on the first line of the address variations:

```
Flat 8 - Actual
8
F8
f8
flat 8
flat8
FLAT8
FLAT 8
```

These ones focuses on second line of the address variations:

```
The Apartment - Actual
Apartment, 
TheApartment
theapartment
the apartment
```

These ones focuses on the third line of the address variations:

```
King Philip Street - Actual
King Philip St
King Philip st
King Philip street
King Philip STREET
king philip St
king philip st
king philip street
king philip STREET
```

These ones focuses on the fourth line of the address variations:

```
SE1 3WX - Actual
SE13WX
SE1 3WX
se1 3wx
se13wx
```

Hence, the Python function should be able to parse and output the above segmented results, once an address input into the function.

I have a few thousand addresses such as this to be parsed as well.

Has anyone done anything like this before, could someone please help to show me how this can be achieved ?

SAMPLE FUNCTION USAGE:

```
Python_Function("Flat 8, The Apartment, King Philip Street, SE1 3WX, England")
```

Output should be:

First line address:

```
Flat 8
8
F8
f8
flat 8
flat8
FLAT8
FLAT 8
```

Second line address:

```
The Apartment
Apartment
TheApartment
theapartment
the apartment
```

Third line address:

```
King Philip Street
King Philip St
King Philip st
King Philip street
King Philip STREET
king philip St
king philip st
king philip street
king philip STREET
```

Fourth line address:

```
SE1 3WX
SE13WX
SE1 3WX
se1 3wx
se13wx
```

Fifth line address:

```
England
england
eng
```

Comment: Post a sample output?

Comment: Any reason why you wouldn't just do a `split(',')`?

Comment: ya, what @GBrandt said, or even better : `.split(', ')` (to avoid sup spaces at start of some values)

Comment: Split would split the text and produce outputs. But I also need variations where, I need to produce both lowercase, uppercase, spaces in between (mimicking how people actually write addresses on papers).

Comment: Have you actually tried anything?

Answer (score 1):

Ditch the hard-coded approach for a more generic approach.

I provided the start (logic for flat and apartment). Hopefully you will manage to do the rest on your own.

```
import re
from itertools import product

digits_regex = re.compile('\d+')

address = "Flat 8, The Apartment, King Philip Street, SE1 3WX, England"

def generate(full_address):
    def generate_flat(flat_number, prefixes=('f', 'flat')):
        flat_options = [str(flat_number)]
        for prefix in prefixes:
            flat_options.append('{}{}'.format(prefix, flat_number))
            flat_options.append('{} {}'.format(prefix, flat_number))
            flat_options.append('{}{}'.format(prefix.upper(), flat_number))
            flat_options.append('{} {}'.format(prefix.upper(), flat_number))
        return flat_options

    def generate_apartment(apartment):
        prefix, *rest = apartment.split()
        joined = ''.join((prefix, *rest))
        return [apartment, rest[0], joined, joined.lower(), ' '.join((prefix.lower(), *map(str.lower, rest)))]

    flat, apartment, street, area, country = full_address.split(', ')

    return [', '.join(variation) for variation in product(generate_flat(digits_regex.findall(flat)[0]), generate_apartment(apartment))]


for variation in generate(address):
    print(variation)
```

Output

```
8, The Apartment
8, Apartment
8, TheApartment
8, theapartment
8, the apartment
f8, The Apartment
f8, Apartment
f8, TheApartment
f8, theapartment
f8, the apartment
f 8, The Apartment
f 8, Apartment
f 8, TheApartment
f 8, theapartment
f 8, the apartment
F8, The Apartment
F8, Apartment
F8, TheApartment
F8, theapartment
F8, the apartment
F 8, The Apartment
F 8, Apartment
F 8, TheApartment
F 8, theapartment
F 8, the apartment
flat8, The Apartment
flat8, Apartment
flat8, TheApartment
flat8, theapartment
flat8, the apartment
flat 8, The Apartment
flat 8, Apartment
flat 8, TheApartment
flat 8, theapartment
flat 8, the apartment
FLAT8, The Apartment
FLAT8, Apartment
FLAT8, TheApartment
FLAT8, theapartment
FLAT8, the apartment
FLAT 8, The Apartment
FLAT 8, Apartment
FLAT 8, TheApartment
FLAT 8, theapartment
FLAT 8, the apartment
```

Comment: Hi, the code you provided is really great, but could you please help me by trying to produce an output like the one I showed above in my question ? For example, to have one input, being printed into Five different segments: (First line address, Second line address, Third line address, Fourth line address and so on). I really apologise because I'm very new to coding, overall. I will definitely work on improving and learning from what all of you are sharing me here.

Comment: @Dinesh Then all you need to do is to remove the call to `product` at the end of `generate` and simply print the output of the `generate_flat` and `generate_apartment` functions.

Comment: really sorry, I tried different methods, It's not working. I am definitely doing something wrong. I commented out the return function and replace the last line with the one you mentioned, I'm getting none as the output. Ultimately, if the function is able to output all the segments in one go, without multiple different function calls would be really great.

Comment: is it possible to remove the following: address = "Flat 8, The Apartment, King Philip Street, SE1 3WX, England" and allow for the function to be able to accept any similar address inputs and have the function output desired segments from the address ?

Answer (score -1):

Here is a quick go with some tools that can be useful (without doing everything in your place) :

```
for i,field in enumerate(input.split(', ')):
    lower_case = field.lower()
    upper_case = field.upper()
    capital = field.proper()
    without_spaces = field.replace(' ','') # you can remove spaces for above as well

    #then you can had specifics
    if i == 1:
        only_first_three = field[:3]

    #now if someones really writes weirdly:
    splitted_field = field.split(' ')
    random_capitals = [ word.proper() for word in splitter_fields if ...]
```